# PermissionError(13, 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process') while installing kivy on anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, kivy

I am trying to install kivy through anaconda promt.
I am getting the following result,

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda install -c conda-forge kivy
Solving environment: /
Warning: 2 possible package resolutions (only showing differing packages):
  - conda-forge::sdl2_image-2.0.2-0
  - conda-forge::sdl2_image-2.0.2-vc14done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\vedan\Anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - kivy


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    glew:            2.0.0-he025d50_1002     conda-forge
    kivy:            1.10.1-py36h47ee06f_1   conda-forge
    krb5:            1.16.3-hdd46e55_1001    conda-forge
    sdl2:            2.0.8-h6538335_1001     conda-forge
    sdl2_image:      2.0.2-0                 conda-forge
    sdl2_mixer:      2.0.1-h6538335_1        conda-forge
    sdl2_ttf:        2.0.14-h8909db8_1       conda-forge
    smpeg2:          2.0.0-h6538335_1        conda-forge

The following packages will be REMOVED:

    anaconda:        5.2.0-py36_3

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    ca-certificates: 2018.03.07-0                        --> 2018.11.29-ha4d7672_0   conda-forge
    certifi:         2018.4.16-py36_0                    --> 2018.11.29-py36_1000    conda-forge
    conda:           4.5.4-py36_0                        --> 4.6.7-py36_0            conda-forge
    cryptography:    2.2.2-py36hfa6e2cd_0                --> 2.5-py36h7a1dbc1_0
    curl:            7.60.0-h7602738_0                   --> 7.64.0-h4496350_2       conda-forge
    freetype:        2.8-h51f8f2c_1                      --> 2.8.1-ha63716d_1        conda-forge
    libcurl:         7.60.0-hc4dcbb0_0                   --> 7.64.0-h4496350_2       conda-forge
    libpng:          1.6.34-h79bbb47_0                   --> 1.6.36-h7602738_1000    conda-forge
    libssh2:         1.8.0-hd619d38_4                    --> 1.8.0-h642c060_1004     conda-forge
    openssl:         1.0.2o-h8ea7d77_0                   --> 1.1.1b-hfa6e2cd_0       conda-forge
    pycurl:          7.43.0.1-py36h74b6da3_0             --> 7.43.0.2-py36h7a1dbc1_0
    qt:              5.9.5-vc14he4a7d60_0                --> 5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0
    sqlite:          3.23.1-h35aae40_0                   --> 3.26.0-hfa6e2cd_1000    conda-forge
    tk:              8.6.7-hcb92d03_3                    --> 8.6.9-hfa6e2cd_1000     conda-forge
    vc:              14-h0510ff6_3                       --> 14.1-h0510ff6_4
    vs2015_runtime:  14.0.25123-3                        --> 14.15.26706-h3a45250_0

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred while uninstalling package 'defaults::qt-5.9.5-vc14he4a7d60_0'.
PermissionError(13, 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process')
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done
```

---

```
PermissionError(13, 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process')
```

Even running promt as administrator i am getting the same error.
Pls provide the solution if possible.

Comment: Try installing in a another environment, not base. It's possible that some packages that are being updated are in use by som other processes.

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the same problem. I closed all my python windows (Like, spyder / pycharm, etc). Then did the conda install again and it worked. Try closing all python related windows and then try installing.